# Example of fourier series diverges at least two points

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I know continuous function $f$ such that fourier series of $f$ diverges at one point. 
But, I don't know continuous function such that fourier series of $f$ diverges at least two point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the basic properties of Fourier series is *localization*: If $f=0$ in a neighborhood of $t$ then the Fourier series for $f$ converges to $0$ at $t$. Hence if $f=g$ in a neighborhood of $t$ then the two Fourier series either both converge at $t$ or both diverge at $t$.

So: Given $f_1$ with a divergent series at $t_1$ and $f_2$ with a divergent series at $t_2$ concoct $g$ so that $g=f_1$ in a neighborhood of $t_1$ and $g=f_2$ in a neighborhood of $t_2$.

Comment: I only know that fourier series of function diverges at x=0 .,,, How to make fourier series of function diverges at other point?..

Comment: @asfajaf Oh dear. If $g(t)=f(t-a)$ then $s_n(g,t) =s_n(f,t-a)$.